# Assign role to imported users via SQL

Tags: wordpress

I imported like almost 600 users from a db inside wp_users and I’d like to assign default role to all users imported via SQL… I know capability is usually stored in wp_usermeta with metakey = ‘wp_capabilities’ and actually I see only administrator role in meta_value field….. How I can assign default subscriber role to all those almost 600 users via SQL? Thanks in advance to all!!

Answer (score 0):

To set one user, if you know the ID, to a subscriber role, run these two SQL queries.

```sql
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
       VALUES (:id, 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}');
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
       VALUES (:id, 'wp_user_level', '0');
```

The first query inserts a capabilities array like this:

```php
array ('subscriber' => true)
```

and the second sets the user level to 0. User level is mostly a legacy setting, but some plugins require it.

Setting all your new users' capabilites and levels is slightly more tricky, because you need a list of the ones to set.  If your newly imported users don't have any `wp_capabilities` setting yet, you can put the list of user IDs in a temporary table like this:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_users
SELECT wp_users.ID
  FROM wp_users
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  
          ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
         AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
 WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id IS NULL;
```

Then you can use that temporary table for inserting all the meta you need.

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID, 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}' FROM new_users;
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID, 'wp_user_level', '0' FROM new_users;
```

**Careful** If you're using a WordPress multisite instance the procedure is more complex.  And, this depends on your new users having no capability or level settings at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you O. Jones,
at the end I decided to implement a little PHP procedure where I call wp_insert_user() because I read user data from the other table I am importing from with success! Thanks again!